# Working out which Portable Class Library profiles can reference each other

Tags: .net, visual-studio, portable-class-library

Is there any way of working out programatically (so not trying it within visual studio) which of the various portable class library profiles can reference each other?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it's a little convoluted. Under the reference assemblies folders, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile158\SupportedFrameworks`, there are files that indicate what platforms are supported. From there, you can figure whether a given portable project is compatible with another.

To save time, NuGet's written a bunch of logic that figures this out, that was added in this check-in: http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/e6a7dad9ceb8